# Login GITLAB usando request

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

Estou tentando fazer login no gitlab usando a biblioteca requests do python porem está apresentando o erro (The change you requested was rejected (422))

Obs. Não posso utilizar nenhuma biblioteca externa(Selenium, bs4, mechanizer).

Obs2. Removi o login e senha do Data por questões de segurança.

segue código a baixo:

```
import requests

headers = {

'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36',
'Accept-Language': 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
 }

data = {
'utf8': '\u2713',
'authenticity_token': '1iTsnSyWPBSq21gKe5_z',
'user[login]': 'login',
'user[password]': 'senha',

}

 response = requests.post('https://gitlab.com/users/sign_in', 
 headers=headers, data=data)


 print(response.content)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este erro ocorre porque o `authenticity_token` muda a todo momento, provavelmente é um anti-CSRF (Cross-site request forgery), a unica maneira de fazer isto funcionar seria seguir os seguintes passos:

- Um requisição GET em `https://gitlab.com/users/sign_in` e usar os cookies assim:

  ```
  import requests

  session = requests.Session()

  response = session.get('https://gitlab.com/users/sign_in')

  #contem a resposta da página
  html = response.text
  ```
- Na sequencia deve pegar o valor do atributo `value` de `<input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="..." />` que veio da requisição get, para isto pode usar a lib https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/, instale com pip:

  ```
  pip install beautifulsoup4
  ```

  Deve ficar algo como:

  ```
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
  authenticity_token = soup.find('input', {'name': 'authenticity_token'}).get('value')
  ```
- E por fim autenticar:

  ```
  data = {
      'utf8': '\u2713',
      'authenticity_token': authenticity_token,
      'user[login]': 'login',
      'user[password]': 'senha'
  }

  response = session.post('https://gitlab.com/users/sign_in', headers=headers, data=data)
  ```

**Note** que mudei `request.post` para `session.post`, porque é preciso ter acesso ao cookie setado pelo próprio gitlab para ele reconhecer o token.

MAS JÁ LHE ADIANTO, só sugeri a resposta acima para fins de estudo, este meio de obter os dados não é lá muito confiável, já que se um anti-bot ou anti-ddos suspeitar já vai logo lhe barrar, eu creio que a API oficial do Gitlab seja o caminho para você poder obter os resultados desejados, acesse:

- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/

Recomendo que mude a abordagem antes de fazer muito trabalho desnecessário, usar a API oficial no começo vai lhe exigir um pouco de estudo mas vai lhe ajudar a evitar muitos problemas.